# Web Api with Auth0 Authentication

Tags: auth0

I am working on Web Api call to authenticate using Auth0. I am able to get token
but when I am making calls to Web Api to get it is giving UnAuthorize 401 even I am sending the Authorize. Below is my code in Web Api project:

[image]

Call to Auth0 to authticate and get token

[image]

Comment: You need to provide significant more information than that... Do you mean ASP.NET Web API? If so, which flavor (full framework, core)? How did you configure it to accept Auth0 issued tokens? Did you do that from scratch or used an available sample? Also, images may be great for you to quickly include information, not so great for people that will most of the times need to reproduce the issue and copy/paste code/data in order to help you.

Comment: Why isn't your token in the `Authorization` tab?